# Rails: test single file with rake test without resetting database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, load-testing

With Rails and TestCase I can do rake test:all **without touching db**.
Some time i need to test only one file and not the entire suite without touching db.
How can i do the same thing but with single file?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to run single test file, then below is the answer

```
rake test TEST=path_to_test_file
```

Comment: I need the same functionality but without recreate db. Like in rake test:all. In rails 4 you can test single file also without prefix TEST=.